# mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpmibs.so.31: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb

Sharing below the output of my server info.

[root@HBAPIPUATAP13 mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-4.0.1]# uname -a
Linux HBAPIPUATAP13 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 21 09:07:21 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@HBAPIPUATAP13 mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-4.0.1]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

Answer (score 1):

The below packages need to be installed before starting mongod process.

yum install cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-gssapi cyrus-sasl-plain krb5-libs libcurl libpcap lm_sensors-libs net-snmp net-snmp-agent-libs openldap openssl rpm-libs tcp_wrappers-libs

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/